# Incorrect syntax for T-sql with Json_value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, t-sql

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE [context.custom.dimensions.properties, '$.ste.app.hcpname'] AS People
```

I am getting an error :Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Anyone know why?

Comment: mysql supports tsql?!?

Comment: why you have tag  mysql  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shown in above query getting any data from the table. You have used JSON_VALUE then please refer this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

You have used as a keyword like this.
SELECT N'{
     "info":{
       "type":1,
       "address":{
         "town":"Bristol",
         "county":"Avon",
         "country":"England"
       },
       "tags":["Sport", "Water polo"]
    },
    "type":"Basic"
 }' AS  JSON_VALUE

Answer (score 0):

In TSQL, the syntax is:

```
JSON_VALUE ( expression , path )
```

You seem to be missing parenthesis.